# ANDROID STUDIO start failed!! what to do?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

I was working on android studio and it was working fine until i tried to update the packages from the sdk manager and it didnt get completed (reached almost 75% and then stopped possibly due to weak network connection). Now when i try to open android studio it shows a dialog box titled start failed java.lang.runtimeexception and a lot more codes written in it...
tried everything, installing the latest version of android studio from google's site. NOT worked ! still the same problem..
tried to change the idea.properties file.. DIDNT WORKED TOO!!
closed my internet connection... same thing occured..
Seriously looking for a solution....

Comment: do a clean AS install.

Comment: uninstall with Iobit uninstaller

Comment: whats a clean AS install

Comment: Move Android SDK somewhere else.

Comment: you mean installing the sdk in any other directory than the default one??

Comment: @rishisingh Yes. Move broken one to someware else where Android Studio does not know, then install default Android SDK (maybe with Android Studio installer).

Comment: when i tried to install the android studio the sdk installation path was default\sdk1 instead of sdk... i did the install but the same problem occurs again..

Comment: How about uninstall Android Studio and re-install it? Same problem occurs?

Comment: yupp!! now i have two sdk folders in appdata.. sdk1 and sdk . im using windows 10

Comment: Android Studio has SDK path setting, so after boot is sccess, decide which one to use.

Comment: 1. Check TEMP folder. Android Studio often fills it up while updating SDK.

Comment: 2. Start SDK manager.exe in SDK folder. If it shows broken ones, delete them.

Comment: finally!!!! its working....  Cleared the temp folder inside sdk and deleted the broken ones from the sdk... I dont know which one helped but it worked.. thanks @Toris

Answer (score 1):

it took me a whole day to solve this issue... @Toris was right..
Delete the broken packages from the sdk manager or clear the TEMP folder under USER/AppData/Local/Android/sdk directory...
 THANKS AGAIN @Toris

Comment: NB: 1.Clearing temp folder recovers SDK download problem. (If it is filled up, download stops, and often leaves broken packages.) 2.Broken packages may prevent booting Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If someone having this same problem then what you can do is:
Go to help and Check for updates then download the patch
and restart your IDE.

Problem was plugins and with the update you will see this:

[image]

This means that your plugins are becoming compatible with the latest version.

Other options:

1. Invalidate caches and restart
2. Sync with gradle files
3. Rename the marketPlace folder [C:\Users\USERNAME.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins]